# vagrant não está conseguido encontrar virtualbox guest additions e kernel module

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Eu tentei instalar e atualizar o vagrant-vbguest

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei modificar o arquivo vagrantfile

```
  # set auto_update to false, if you do NOT want to check the correct 
  # additions version when booting this machine
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false

  # do NOT download the iso file from a webserver
  config.vbguest.no_remote = true
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instalei a versão anterior do virtualbox v5.0.36 funcionou depois disso.